# Writing an linearithmic algorithm

Tags: algorithm

This is a question for one of my assignments.

> Given four lists of N names, devise a linearithmic algorithm to determine if there is any name common to all four lists.

The closest I've come to a solution that satisfies O(n log n), only works if there are only two data sets. Iterating through one of the sets and using binary search to find a match.

Any hints on how to solve this? I first posted this on programmers.stackexchange, but most of the replies mistook linearithmic for linear.

Comment: Maybe you should ask here instead: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm you proposed can be extended to work with any (constant) number of lists:

- Sort all the lists but one, using an O(n * log n) sort.
- Iterate over the unsorted list.
- For each item, use binary search on each sorted list to see if it is present in them all.

This takes the same amount of time as your solution, multiplied by a constant (the number of lists). So it is still O(n * log n).

Note that it is also possible to get an O(n) average-case runtime by using hash tables instead of sort + binary search.

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression this would somehow alter the complexity of the algorithm. I'm glad I was wrong in this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Sort all four lists in O(N.Log(N)).

Then sequentially select the smallest among the four lists (this takes a constant number of comparison per element) until all lists are exhausted, in O(N). In case of ties, you will progress in all lists with the same value (an report quadruple ties).