# Linearithmic search of commons in lists

Tags: java, list, runtime, binary-search

This will be my first question in here, so please be kind. I've searched for answers and I found something *very* similar: [Writing an linearithmic algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700131/writing-an-linearithmic-algorithm)

(Unfortunately "linearithmic" does not seem to be a tag, so it's a bit hard to find other similar problems.)

I've been asked to do the same as in the link above, except to find whether or not there is any name common to *at least* three of the four lists, and if so return the lexicographically first such name.

I've followed the steps in the link above, though I've decided to sort all four lists. Given that a name could be in either the first list and at least two others, or in the three other lists, I've ended up with two distinct for-loops (not nested) whereas I do a binary-search. The question is, does this still fulfill the linearithmic requirement?

I'm a bit at odds with it, since the sorting of the lists itself is a N logN-problem, and then inside of my first for-loop I have three different possibilities with the binary-search, which is 3N logN, and then a second for-loop which yields N logN. Do I understand it correct when saying that this amounts to 5N logN, which is some scalar a (=5)*N logN and that makes it a O(N logN)-problem? Could someone please clarify for me, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why the `List`s need to be sorted.  Can you use a `Set`?  Populate three `Set`s from three of the `List`s.  Then iterate over the last `List` and count how many hits in the `Set`s.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In order to preform a binary-search I understand that the lists (or sets) I want to find commons with needs to be sorted. I don't understand how populating a set would allow me to reach the desired runtime-complexity any differently?